# What is the meaning of 'mental yoga ' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does *mental yoga* mean in the following sentence?

> The isNaN() function requires some `mental yoga` at times because it
>   attempts to prove a negative—that the value in a variable is not a
>   number.

Comment: Consider that the answer needs some mental yoga on the OP's part, that is, to exercise the brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yoga* here is being used as a metaphor for flexibility.

Because the function attempts to do what's widely considered impossible -- proving a negative -- it demands that you stretch your mind a bit to comprehend it.

In addition to *mental yoga*, you might run into the phrase *mental gymnastics*, which has largely the same meaning.